# C variable declaration

Tags: c

What is the difference between

```
char *a[10];
```

and

```
char *(a[10]);
```

I've always used the first for an array of char pointers, but now I've found code used the second.
As I was not sure if it was the same thing, I printed sizeof() both and both return 80 (64bit OS) so I'm inclined to believe both are the same (an array of char pointers).

But as I cannot find any explanation online or anything using *([]) syntax, I was looking for some confirmation.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two are equivalent and stand for a 10-element array of pointers to `char`.

Contrast with `char (*a)[10]`, which is a pointer to a 10-element array of `char`.

If in doubt, one could use [`cdecl`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/cdecl1.html) to unscramble C declarations. On Unix it's usually available as a command-line tool. There's also an [online version](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 1):

`char *a[10];` and `char *(a[10]);` are the same. To make it clear lets say it this way, `char *a[10];` is `pointer array` of 10 and later is array of 10 where `all are pointers`!  You see that both are same with different way of saying that.